# Why I am getting error 404 with Spring-boot and thymeleaf on an existing source?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a simple web application written on java 8 using spring boot and `thymeleaf` with the following dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>serving-web-content-initial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>serving-web-content-initial</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

with just one controller :

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

under the resource folder of the same module (resources/templates/greeting.html) i have a sample html :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'"/>
</body>
</html>
```

application properties is basically empty containing only the following line: `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG`

the request on URL http://localhost:8080/greeting is always returning error 404 no matter if accessed with http or https and without difference of the browser used.

Am I missing a part of the configuration or is it wrong? What can be the cause of this? Can it not be related with my project and be caused by some other configuration on my computer? Any suggestions will be appreciated great.

P.S. I have downgraded from version 2.5.2 of spring-boot-starter-parent to its lower version 2.4.10 and the problem is fixed.

Comment: please put  `appliaction.properties` and what is the name of your html page

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej 
application properties is basically empty containing only the following line: logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG - this is the full content of application.properties file found in src/main/resources/application.properties
the name and path of the html is src/main/resources/static/greeting.html

Comment: `greeting.html` put in `templates` folder because every `html` or `jsp` file create in `templates` folder

Comment: `css`,`js`,`json`,`images` etc put in static folder

Comment: Thank you! I completed theese steps but weirdly I still get the error 404

Answer (score 3):

Just add this in application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix= classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix= .html
```

Comment: Great suggestion! But it still gives error 404.

Comment: You want to display full code for solve your problem because little mistake is responsible for error `404`